# Strange color on buttons?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, design

It seems the buttons have a strange color that doesn't match anything else on the site.
[image: button-color-demonstration]

Comment: Indeed. Even the trilogy or sketchy buttons would fit in more than those.

Comment: It makes them very visible, but I don't think they need to be. And I would like them to have more contrast, I can barely make out the text.

Answer (score 1):

I actually like them. It's a nice color (whatever it's name is). It adds a bit of life to the (kinda) dull theme. Also, note that the same color is used for the bronze badges.

Comment: which I never see on the same page. like I said in comment to @michael, there's just not enough of this color on the page to make it work.

Answer (score 1):

This is by design. The buttons need to stand out a bit more. Also the orange tone is complimentary to the blues used elsewhere on the site.

Comment: I don't like it I think it's **ugly**. I do agree with @tshepang's comment elsewhere that meta looks better than parent

Comment: @xeno You want the buttons to be grey like on meta?

Comment: @michael idk, I'm not a designer, but they just don't look right, they might be color complementary, but they don't look attractive, possibly because their isn't enough of it, it seems like the only place that color is used (even if it's not). Meta seems a more consistent theme. The grey works better on meta because there's lots of shades of it already.

Comment: @michael I don't think grey would work either because there's no grey on the parent. though I'd ask if something has been tuned on this already, or if I'm just getting used to it, because it looks less horrific than it did.